# How to align group components to the left

Tags: java, layout, swt, grid-layout

I want to use group boxes to improve my GUI. However when adding components to a `Group` they move to the center of the box and are not left aligned anymore. How do I get each button and text to move to the left margin. 
[image: Group Box with centered elements]

Code

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, true);
layout.marginWidth = 300;
Group group = new Group(this, SWT.SHADOW_OUT);
group.setText("Open file locations");
group.setLayout(layout);

Button optionOne = new Button(group, SWT.CHECK | SWT.LEFT);
optionOne.setText(AppMessages.msg("Open file A") );

Button optionTwo = new Button(group, SWT.LEFT | SWT.CHECK);
optionTwo.setText(AppMessages.msg("Open file B") );
```

[Need Space between two groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN2bf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u try to remove marginWidth from the layout

Comment: I need the Group Box to be that wide. So when I take out the margin the elements are left aligned but the box is not wide enough. I inserted this marginWidth value so it is aligned to the next element in the GUI.

Comment: You can use GridLayoutData and set widthHint to set the width of the control

Comment: Worked! Thank you @Doan Linh

Comment: I did add a vote but for some reason if did not stay in there. Most probably i did it wrong. I'm new here. I just have to click the up arrow right? awww and by the way how would I add space between two group boxes following each other. I added the image of the issue on the original question.

Comment: im new too.. and yes, i think its the up arrow.. 
for your question, try to use the same `GidData data` that you add `widthHint`, now add `verticalIndent`

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are left aligned but you have specified a margin of 300 pixels to go to the left of the buttons before the alignment is done.

The margin values your specify for a layout of a `Group` or `Composite` set the margins within the control.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by set the margins within the control>

Comment: I mean the left margin you set with `layout.marginWidth = 300` is 300 pixels within the outline drawn by the Group control. That is why your buttons are spaced 300 pixels from the left of the Group.